# Resources for QML hackathon/textbook types of questions

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, resource-request

I'm looking for a list of resources (links, videos, lectures, etc.) that contains quantum machine learning problems. These could be of the style of problem sets, hackathon questions, questions from a textbook, or anything similar.

The difficulty could be any level, but problems that would take a bit more than just searching up a theorem, definition or Qiskit/Cirq function are preffered. This without going to the other extreme of having to go down a rabbit hole to answer a super-niche question.

Any links to pages with such problems or to any specific problem of this type are appreciated.

Comment: The QHack 2021 github repo is archived and contains sets of challenge problems related to tasks like taking derivatives of quantum circuits and optimizing VQE: https://github.com/XanaduAI/QHack2021

Answer (score 2):

There are many demos on https://pennylane.ai/qml/demonstrations.html. You could perhaps get some inspiration from there.